# In Asp.net MVC how to create available and selected Listbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox

I am a novoice and I like to know an example working model, view and controller where I can display available options in a listbox and select and add to a selected options to a selected listbox and finally submit the form with selection list box options in a asp.net mvc as shown in the screenshot. Please provide code example code for controller, model and view[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is a poor design. You need javascript to move the items and ensure that every item is selected in the RHS list box immediately before you submit. Why not one list box (the selected items will post back to your model)

Comment: As I requested I am a novice student (5 days into web development). It would be kind of you if you please help me understand the concept behind this or point me to the right study material.

Comment: A single list box is all that is needed, and the user can select the required items from that list, although if there are a lot of items that mean scrolling through the list, then its not obvious to the user which items are selected so the best solution depends on other factors you need to consider.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your guidance..